# Could not open X display after hostname change

Tags: hostname, fedora

I need to change the hostname of my Computer from `localhost.localdomain` to `DESKTOP`. However, I can't manage to do this, even after browsing some of the net.

I've changed my hostname with `hostname DESKTOP`

The best informations I've found so far  as in there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611783/after-changing-hostname-gedit-not-open

However, once my hostname is changed to `DESKTOP`, I can't access `gedit` or any other thing that are IHM-linked in my terminal, as a root user. Which I need to do.

```
$ xauth list
xauth : file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
```

I can't get to add something to `xauth`, I've tried to type this:

```
$ xauth add ${DESKTOP}/unix:0 . [Same key as in xauth list as normal user]
```

Which gives me:

```
$ xauth: (argv):1:  bad display name "/unix:0" in "add" command
```

Is there a way to get this to work? I'm on the same machine, I don't use SSH.

Oddly, I seem to be able to use `gedit` if I use `sudo -i` to log as `sudo`. But why? And how can I get to work permanently with `su` to log?

Comment: How did you manage to change the host's name? I use F19 and F20 and have set my hostname and do not suffer from this particular issue. I've generally used these methods in the past to set my system's (Fedora) hostname: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6364/one-liner-how-to-change-the-hostname-on-a-fedoracentosrhel-system/#more-6364

Comment: I used `hostname DESKTOP`. I can't access your link, there is an error, could you check it ?

Comment: Try adding `127.0.0.1 [your hostname]` to /etc/hosts.

Comment: Yeah it's my blog, it's not accessible to some parts of the world.

Comment: @xhaltar - here this shows essentially the same methods: http://www.labtestproject.com/using_linux/permanently_change_hostname_on_fedora

Comment: The reason why `xauth add ${DESKTOP}/unix:0` didn't work for you seems to be that ${DESKTOP} expanded to an empty string (i.e., this variable was not set). Otherwise, the situation is similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/234494/4319 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611783/after-changing-hostname-gedit-and-other-x-clients-dont-open ; giving the new hostname for `xauth` should help (or setting it to **FamilyWild**).